# How to make a tone with 56k modem?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, console-application, dial-up

I have a USB 56K Modem, and a locked door in a condominium.

When a user "dials" me, I must "anwser then press 6" on the phone. 
So I'm trying to send a tone to the cable....

I've added a new Windows 10 remote dial-up connection to the number 6. Named "door"

So in console I would get:  **rasphone -d door**

But doesnt works.....
How can I open this dooor with my computer? [Android :D]

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO.

Comment: Can I write a small C# program that ding dong the modem?

Comment: Do you want this done in Windows or in DOS? You have tagged it as a DOS question, but you do not have .net in DOS. And to be clear the command line is NOT the same thing as DOS. DOS is an operating system that few people have used for roughly 15-20 years.

Comment: So you're trying to write an app that lets any random person who presses your button on the entry into your building or complex, without first verifying who they are? How do your neighbors (who think they're living in a secure building or complex) feel about that? How about the building management?

Comment: It can be a DOS command, it can be in VB.net or C#, no importance, I just want it to work. Solution can be also an already existing software...

Comment: The DTMF will be sent at a specified moment with my cellphone remotely connected to my computer, I'll know the exact moment the person is calling.
We just don't want to change the entire system, wich could cost over 10k$... 
I tought a simple question on StackOv. would cost less :)

Answer (score 0):

The modem waits for the dial tone before sending the DTMF codes. You have to get your modem to send ATDT command without dial tone.

Comment: I mean, In real-life, I would pick the phone then it rings and then press the button #6 to trigger the door to open...       

I'm just trying to find a way to "awnser a call" with the computer and press 6

Comment: Yes. Modems are not designed to send DTMF codes when the they answer the call, thus there is no dial tone. They use DTMF for dialing out.

Comment: My objective is to be remote connected to my computer with a remote software, then execuse any batch or pre-programmed program to only send a DTMF (ex connecting to "6") to make trigger the door open... It doesn't need to wait for a call I think.

Comment: I didn't write waiting for a call. I wrote waiting for dial tone.

Comment: By the way, why don't you use a sound card to emit DTMF codes?

Comment: Could be nice, but how to plug my soundcard on the phone lines lol

Comment: generating DTMF dial tones with a soundcard is trivial with tools like [dtmfdial](https://github.com/TJNII/dtmfdial), but i dont know yet how to connect my soundcard to the phone line without breaking something...